# Distributing random numbers with multiple conditions

Tags: r, random, while-loop, conditional-statements

My students handed in group projects. Now they are supposed to give feedback to other student's works. Each student should give feedback to two other student projects. I want to assign these projects randomly. Two conditions have to be met:

1. A student should not give feedback to their own project.
2. A student should not give feedback to the same project twice.
3. The number of feedback for different groups should be the same in feedback1 and feedback1 (if group 3 receives feedback 3 times in feedback1, they need to receive feedback 3 times in feedback2).

```
#Example Data
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
name <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
feedback1 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
feedback2 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
df <- data.frame(group, name, feedback1, feedback2)
```

As you can see, the groups are not the same size (some groups have 2 members, some have 3). I created a loop that checks if someone is about to give feedback to himself. If so, a random number is chosen from all the group numbers, until a fitting number is chosen. One occurrence of the chosen number is then removed from the group numbers and the next student is checked.

```
# Fill feedback1
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  while (df$feedback1[i] == df$group[i]) {
    df$feedback1[i] <- sample(group, 1)
  }
  group <- group[-match(df$feedback1[i], group)]
}
```

This works so far:

```
   group name feedback1 feedback2
1      1    a         2         1
2      1    b         3         1
3      1    c         3         1
4      2    d         1         2
5      2    e         1         2
6      3    f         4         3
7      3    g         4         3
8      3    h         2         3
9      4    i         1         4
10     4    j         3         4
```

If I add the second condition ("students should not give feedback to the same groups") the loop fails to work:

```
# Fill feedback2
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  while (df$feedback2[i] == df$group[i] & df$feedback1[i] == df$feedback2[i] ) {
    df$feedback2[i] <- sample(group, 1)
  }
  group <- group[-match(df$feedback2[i], group)]
}
```

I do not get an error message, but df$feedback2 just stays the same for all students:

```
 group name feedback1 feedback2
1      1    a         2         1
2      1    b         3         1
3      1    c         3         1
4      2    d         1         2
5      2    e         1         2
6      3    f         4         3
7      3    g         4         3
8      3    h         2         3
9      4    i         1         4
10     4    j         3         4
```

1. What is the mistake in my second loop for feedback2?
2. What would be (in general) a better way to do approach the problem?

Best regards

Comment: are you sure feedback needs to be random? If so: how to prevent that a project will not receive feedback at all, while an other project receives >5 feedback?

Comment: the number in feedback1 and feedback2 represent group numbers. e.g. in line one: "Person A in Group 1 has to give feedback to Group 2 and Group 3" (it says Group 1 in my data, this is exactly where the error is).

Answer (score 1):

Actually looping is not an R'ly style way for this case. I would offer the following `tidyverse` solution (note you dont need to assign feedbackn columns prior to evaluating the script):

```
library(tidyverse)

possibleGroups <- df$group %>% unique()
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(fb = sample(possibleGroups[possibleGroups != group], size = 2) %>% `names<-`(paste(c("feedback"), 1:2)) %>%  list()
) %>% 
  unnest_wider(fb)
```

This results into:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   group name  `feedback 1` `feedback 2`
   <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1 a                2            4
 2     1 b                4            2
 3     1 c                3            4
 4     2 d                3            4
 5     2 e                1            3
 6     3 f                1            4
 7     3 g                1            4
 8     3 h                4            1
 9     4 i                3            1
10     4 j                2            3
```

Let me know if I need to give any details to how it works.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), name = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: I think I understood what you did. I edited my questions with a third thing that should be checked. In what way do we need to change your code to make that possible? (Thanks for reminding me that I really need to start working with tibbles ...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way. It samples two projects at a time, from the projects not each student's. Then assigns names to the results matrix and binds it with the first two columns of the original data set.

```r
prj <- unique(group)

set.seed(2023)
fb <- apply(df[1:2], 1L, \(x) sample(prj[prj != x[1L]], 2L))
cbind(df[1:2], fb |> t() |> `colnames<-`(c("feedback1", "feedback2")))
#>    group name feedback1 feedback2
#> 1      1    a         2         3
#> 2      1    b         4         2
#> 3      1    c         4         3
#> 4      2    d         3         1
#> 5      2    e         1         4
#> 6      3    f         1         4
#> 7      3    g         1         4
#> 8      3    h         4         2
#> 9      4    i         3         1
#> 10     4    j         1         2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-18</sup>